# How to read file from the salt user's home directory in salt-mine

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to setup a salt-mine that would collect public SSH keys from the minions.  For this I want to use `file.read` module and simply get the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. Problem is that `file.read` fails when run from `mine.update` (but executes fine when run by `salt-call file.read ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`):

```
[ERROR   ] Function public-ssh-key in mine_functions failed to execute
[DEBUG   ] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/modules/mine.py", line 165, in update
    data[func] = __salt__[mine_func](*m_data[func])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/modules/file.py", line 3513, in read
    with salt.utils.files.fopen(path, access_mode) as file_obj:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/utils/files.py", line 399, in fopen
    f_handle = open(*args, **kwargs)  # pylint: disable=resource-leakage
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'
```

Simply using the absolute path (e.g. `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) is not an option because it's not guaranteed that it will always be a root user that runs salt-minion (and not always on *nix, at that).

I use salt 2019.2.0, and my config is as follows.

```
# /srv/pillar/top.sls
base:
  '*':
    - mine.public-ssh-key
```

```
# /srv/pillar/mine/public-ssh-key.sls
mine_functions:
  public-ssh-key:
    - mine_function: file.read
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 0):

Salt does not expand `~` by design.  I managed to work around this via:

```
# /srv/pillar/mine/public-ssh-key.sls
mine_functions:
  public-ssh-key:
    - mine_function: cmd.run
{% if grains['os_family'] == 'Windows' %}
    - {{ grains['shell'] }} /c "if exist %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub type %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub"
{% else %}
    - {{ grains['shell'] }} -c 'if [ -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ]; then cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub; else echo ""; fi'
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Saltstack doesn't expand ~, but can't you use `%h` instead?

In the salt documentation regarding the [ssh_auth](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.ssh_auth.html) there's an example for something similar to what you are trying to achieve

```
thatch:
  ssh_auth.present:
    - user: root
    - source: salt://ssh_keys/thatch.id_rsa.pub
    - config: '%h/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```